# How to filter the items through Django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to get the total number of tables own by each users on my application. using `Tables.objects.all().count` returns all total number of tables but I will like to get the number of tables own by each user.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
class Bar(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Tables(models.Model):
    table_no = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=False)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(to=Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def Dashboard(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    reservations = Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user)
    pending = Reservation.objects.filter(status="pending")
    confirmed = Reservation.objects.filter(status="confirmed")

    context = {"reservations":reservations, "pending":pending, "confirmed":confirmed}

    return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/dashboard.html", context)

class Login(View):
    """ Login View."""
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "dashboard/auth/login.html"

    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Email = form.cleaned_data.get('Email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=Email, password=password)
            messages.success(request, "you have logged in successfully ")
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/dashboard')
            else:
                error = "Email or password is incorrect"
        return render(
            request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'error': error})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/<int:pk>/', Dashboard, name="dashboard"),
]
```

templates.html

```
<li {% if request.path == '/dashboard/' %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="{% url 'dashboard' user.pk %}"><i class="ion-home"></i> <span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Lindsay pretty much answered your question here, only query the user you need, for example if this was a view:

```
def all_user_tables(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    tables = Tables.objcets.filter(bar__user_id=user)
    tables_count = tables.count()
    return render(request, 'all_user_tables.html', {'user': user, 
                                                    'tables': tables, 
                                                    'tables_count': tables_count})
```

then in your template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Tables for user {{ user }}</p>
    {% for table in tables %}
        {{ table }}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Total {{ table_count }} tables.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried that but get the error, "Reverse for 'dashboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']"

Comment: I have edited the codes to show what I did.

Comment: in your urls it should be <int:pk> instead of <str:pk> and make sure when you go to the page you pass a pk of existing user

Comment: I have added the template.html in my code. The ```"href="{% url 'dashboard' dashboard.pk %}""``` is giving me issue in it.

Comment: I think this should work the same way as the suggested solution. ```user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id);
reservations = Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user)``` since it is making reference the current logged in user.

Comment: if you want your users to be able to only view their own reservations then yes, the `<int:pk>` part of the url should be removed and user should be queried by the `requser.user` then your url will look like this: `href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"` in the other case, your url should look like this `href="{% url 'dashboard' user.pk %}"`because you are passing a user id for the view to query it, not the dasboard id :)

Comment: I have added the login view. The thing is that after login, I am redirected to locahost:8000/dashboard instead of locahost:8000/dashboard/users_pk/ 

which then result to a page not found error. I then have to manually enter the users_pk in the url before going to the dashboard correctly

Answer (score 1):

Double underscores allows `filter()` to follow ForeignKey relations

```
user = User.objects.get(email="nasir@yahoo.com")
tbl_count = Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user).count()
```

Comment: when I tried that, i got the error "Cannot query "nasir@yahoo.com": Must be "User" instance."

Comment: Then I tried using "Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user.id)". It didn't return anything

Comment: yes, in this example, one must query the user instance first.  I can add it to the example.

Comment: kindly add it please.